# Adding DataFrame to Panel in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create panel with different dataframes, I try to write a function to return this panel. I use some already written function `createNewDf(i)` which returns dataFrame from existing data, depending on given numeric value.

```
def panelCreation():
    dp1 = Panel({})
    for i in range(1,3):
        name = 'X' + str(i)
        name = createNewDf(i)
    dp1.update(name)       # This does not work
    return dp1
```

I can't find a name of the method to put in place of `dp1.update(name)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just creating the Panel out of a dict of DataFrame?

```
In [10]: dd = {}

In [11]: for i in range(1, 3):
   ....:     name = 'X' + str(i)
   ....:     dd[name] = DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))
   ....:     

In [12]: Panel(dd)
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major) x 3 (minor)
Items: X1 to X2
Major axis: 0 to 2
Minor axis: 0 to 2
```

So something like:

```
def panelCreation():
    dd = {}
    for i in range(1,3):
        name = 'X' + str(i)
        dd[name] = createNewDf(i)
    return Panel(dd)
```

Comment: It does do a job, but is there a function like `.append` to add new dataFrames to already existing panel, but do not change to dict.

    `X4 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4))`
    `my_panel.update(X4)`
But this gives me an error

Comment: how about just `my_panel['new'] = X4`

Comment: @ChangShe Oddly, unlike a dict, if the panel is empty to start with (you don't initialize the panel with a populated `DataFrame`), before you add the `new` `DataFrame`, then, when you try to retrieve the `DataFrame` with `my_panel['new']` or `my_panel.get('new')` you only get an empty DataFrame (the data in the DataFrame is ignored). So be careful to initialize a `Panel` with DataFrames before using its `[]` setter to add more.

Comment: @hobs just checked and you're right. Is this documented anywhere? The behavior is very different to Series and DataFrames, you cannot even use `pd.append`

Comment: Thanks for the repro @astrojuanlu ! If you/we don't find it in the obvious places you/we should submit a docs PR. I'm sure they'd appreciate it. And `@ChangShe` should clarify this answer.

Comment: Passing a dict of dataframes to the panel constructor causes any special numpy `dtypes` to be casted to `float64` in my code, came here to find solution.